# How to add an extra project into existing Android operating system source?

Tags: git, manifest, repository, android-source, forall

I am working on kernel development in AOSP, and the kernel repository that I work on is not a part of the operating system. It has an individual git repository. So when I try to push all AOSP sources into the server, I cannot see the kernel sources there.

How can I add a repository (a project) into existing Android source tree?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found the answer at [this link](http://groups.google.com/group/android-porting/browse_thread/thread/78c6e960116f0dee/bcc2a3b4769c1004), but not exactly what I want.

Then I have pushed the kernel repository as a separate project (without using repo forall -c"git push ...).

1. $ repo forall -c'git push ssh://username@myserver/my-aosp-project/$REPO_PROJECT HEAD:refs/heads/master'
2. $ git push ssh://username@myserver/my-aosp-project/kernel.git HEAD:refs/heads/master

And also I have modified manifest.xml file (which is located in the server) by adding this

```
<project path="kernel" name="kernel" />
```